# Jekyll categories will not work if they have spaces

Tags: jekyll

This is my first time using jekyll and I am having some issues with categories

The following works fine:

```
categories:
  - test
  - test1
```

But if I try to have a category with two words, e.g.

```
categories:
- test test
- test1
```

Then the site breaks and I get the following error:

```
Not Found
`/test/test1/2014/10/24/paper-prototype-the-anti-coding-usability-test.html' not found.
```

I've tried all the different front matter formats but cannot get anything to work. It works perfectly fine with tags though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realise that jekyll was adding the categories to the URL, I updated my _config to include permalink: /:title/ so that it doesn't so this anymore. Now its working :)